# How to refresh native ads in specific time using Admob?

Tags: android, admob

I'm working in my Android application and i integrated native ads from Google Admob and it works well as shown in the picture below. But my problem is i want it refresh itself automatically. And this is my code used to refresh the ad. Any ideas? Thanks.

[image]

```
    private void refreshAd() {

        AdLoader.Builder builder = new AdLoader.Builder(this, ADMOB_AD_UNIT_ID);

        builder.forUnifiedNativeAd(new UnifiedNativeAd.OnUnifiedNativeAdLoadedListener() {
            // OnUnifiedNativeAdLoadedListener implementation.
            @Override
            public void onUnifiedNativeAdLoaded(UnifiedNativeAd unifiedNativeAd) {
                // You must call destroy on old ads when you are done with them,
                // otherwise you will have a memory leak.
                if (nativeAd != null) {
                    nativeAd.destroy();
                }
                nativeAd = unifiedNativeAd;
                FrameLayout frameLayout =
                        findViewById(R.id.fl_adplaceholder);
                UnifiedNativeAdView adView = (UnifiedNativeAdView) getLayoutInflater()
                        .inflate(R.layout.activity_ads, null);
                populateUnifiedNativeAdView(unifiedNativeAd, adView);
                frameLayout.removeAllViews();
                frameLayout.addView(adView);
            }

        });

        NativeAdOptions adOptions = new NativeAdOptions.Builder()
                .build();

        builder.withNativeAdOptions(adOptions);

        AdLoader adLoader = builder.withAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to load native ad: "
                        + errorCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).build();

        adLoader.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    }
```